# do while loop causing 100% CPU usage with curl_multi_exec

Tags: php, loops, curl, cpu

This is a loop used in our script with curl. It's causing CPU usage to shoot up to 100%. A friend said "Your computer is looping so fast here it doesn't have time to process the request since it is constantly checking for a finish."... So my question is how can this loop be re-written to slow down? Thanks

```
$running = null;
do {
  curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while($running > 0);
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this: http://php.net/manual/function.curl-multi-select.php

Comment: Using this function is the VITAL step that is missing in the question and in all the other answers so far.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a call to http://php.net/sleep or http://php.net/usleep in every iteration should reduce the CPU usage by allowing other running processes to be scheduled by the operating system.

Comment: sleep() isn't having an affect on the CPU usage, any other thoughts?

Comment: If a value of 1 or 2 does not make any difference then you should investigate http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php. Maybe you have to close some handles or something similar.

Comment: the problem with sleep is that it will block even if the processes are finished. if curl finishes 0.1 second after calling curl_multi_exec you have to wait 0.9 or 1.9 seconds.

Comment: Checking about 90 URL's with sleep(1) caused the script to slow down and take 140seconds to complete...... Currently it finishes in 9seconds were trying curl-multi-exec now

Comment: Try usleep(1). On my system an infinite loop (that increments a variable) without any sleep calls causes 100% CPU usage, while one with a call to usleep(1) causes less than 20% CPU usage. I am aware that sleeping is not the best option, but it may help reduce CPU usage.

Comment: @Webspy usleep(1) does reduce CPU usage to below 20% and steadily as the script is executing. The time to finish is just really long going from around 10 seconds to 140 seconds. The 90 URL's we are checking is for testing, and in production this script will be connecting to 1000 URLs multiple times a day. I do plan to have this setup on Amazon S3 where I can just start multiple instances (servers) and execute like that. But keeping the total execution time to a minimum and CPU is the goal. My coder is working on using multi exec now. Will update with results once available

Comment: I'm not very familiar with cURL, but you should check http://www.php.net/curl-multi-select, as yi_H suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you didn't post whole code. I suppose you are doing something like

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
for ($i = 0; $i < $desiredThreadsNumber; $i++) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    // set up $ch here
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
}
```

You should understand that you haven't run threads yet here. [curl_multi_exec()](http://php.net/function.curl-multi-exec) runs all threads. But it can't run all $desiredThreadsNumber threads simultaneously. If you look on example on [curl_multi_exec()](http://php.net/function.curl-multi-exec) php.net page, you will see that you must wait while curl_multi_exec() run all threads. In other words, you need next nested loop here:

```
$running = null;
do {
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
} while($running > 0);
```

At the end let me suggest you to read this article http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/01/26/how-to-use-curl_multi-without-blocking/ and use code snippet from there, I used it in 2 or 3 projects.

Answer (score 2):

Tried all the solutions provided above but this one worked for me in highly loaded system where on each second there are more than 1k Multi Curl requests are being made.

```
//Execute Handles
$running = null;

do {
    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

while ($running && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {
    if (curl_multi_select($mh) == -1) {
        usleep(1);
    }
    do {
        $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

curl_multi_select (http://php.net/manual/function.curl-multi-select.php) is indeed the way to go, but there are a couple caveats.

First, if curl_multi_exec returns CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM, it has more data to be processed immediately, so should be run again.  Also, it is important to check that curl_multi_exec did not fail immediately; in that case curl_multi_select could block forever.

This should work:

```
do {
    while (CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM === curl_multi_exec($mh, $running)) {};
    if (!$running) break;
    while (curl_multi_select($mh) === 0) {};
} while (true);
```

If anyone sees a good way to avoid the while(true) without duplicating code, please point it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could add `sleep(1)`, which sleeps for one second, into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $running = null;
    do {
        do {
            $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
        } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM && curl_multi_select($mh) === 0 );
    } while($running > 0  && $mrc == CURLM_OK );
```